# Add attachment in Windows 8 mail

Tags: email, windows-8, attachments

How can I send a file attachment from Windows 8 mail? I don't see any button anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click anywhere on the screen to bring up the [**App Bar**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304103641/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/09/06/embracing-ui-on-demand-with-the-app-bar.aspx).
You will then see an `Attachments` button in the lower-left corner.

[image]

This is also how you add text formatting.  (see the other side of the app bar; not shown)

Answer (score 1):

Right click anywhere to bring up the **App Bar** at the bottom. Click on **Attachments**
[image]

You can also use the Windows 8 Share Charm to share Content as Email Attachments. To do so, while using a Modern UI app (not all apps support Sharing though!)

1. Bring up the Share Charm with <kbd>Win+H</kbd>
2. Select **Mail**
   [image]